# Android nested buttons example?

Tags: android, android-layout

When the user clicks the button, my application should show three buttons. How should I do that? Does dynamic layout helps me to do that?

Or if there is an another way to do it, please suggest me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    }
        public void addListenerOnButton() {

            //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                  Intent openBrowser =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mechmerize.com"));
                  startActivity(openBrowser);
                }
            });
            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

        }


            });
}
}
```

I need to display three buttons when the user clicks the button3

Comment: How about switching to another activity? Show what you have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the buttons programmatically on clicking of the first button.
You can add the buttons before with a false visibility and use setVisible(true) for the buttons on clicking of the first button.

Comment: How about using gone and visible methods on the view, it would be more convenient, than creating view programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `LinearLayout` dynamically to your parent Layout. And in this LinearLayout you can have three buttons. (Using [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29))

The other option is to have a XML layout (in XML file) with three buttons in it and you can set the visibility to gone (using [android:visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility)). When the user has clicked the button you can change the visibility using `setVisibility` to visible.

Sorry, I dont have any sample codes at this moment.